# Azure Ad Connect with private domain possible?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to integrate a private domain with Azure Ad? I cannot get it to verify the with the txt record. Its not possible for us to make this domain public but would like to develop with the features of an integrated domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to integrate a private domain with Azure Active Directory. Only public domains can be verified.

Comment: What if the txt file can be placed on a public dns but the IP addresses are not public? This is an internal domain for a University program that is behind a firewall. However, the adfs server is public and in the domain.

Comment: That should work since all Azure AD does is domain verification, regardless of whether the IP addresses are public or not. Federation should also work if, as you say, the IP address for the ADFS server is public.

Comment: If this is a subdomain (priv.example.com) that's private, but the parent domain is public (example.com), the other option you have is to add and verify the parent domain, then add the subdomain--it will not require DNS verification.